# while I am hovering on main category then I am getting a drop down of sub category. but it hiding behind another div. How to prevent

Tags: html, css, django

while I am hovering to an main category I am getting fine sub category drop down but the sub category drop down is hiding behind the image as you can see in the image I have attached.So here I have use "z-index:1" but it is not working so how to solve this issue please let me know

[image]

```
 <div class="dropdownCategory">
                            <a class="dropbtnCat"
                               href="{% url 'coupons' Categories.cat_name %}">{{Categories.cat_name}}<i
                                    class="arrow-indicator fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></br></a>
                            <div class="dropdown-contentCat">
                                {% for subCategories in SubCategoriesBar %}
                                {% if Categories.cat_id == subCategories.parent_id %}
                                <a href="{% url 'coupons' subCategories.cat_name %}">{{subCategories.cat_name}}</a>
                                {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

*css*

```
.dropdown-contentCat {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    z-index: 1;
    left: 101%;
    top: -2px;
    border-top: 2px solid #DB0038;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: What is the `z-index` of the content that is covering the sub-category? What happens if you make the `z-index` of `.dropdown-contentCat` something super high? Example `z-index: 50`?

Comment: ".dropdown-contentCat" is a sub category class name . And I have given z-index:99, although it is not working

Comment: This happens when both the navigation bar is the same z-index level of the content behind. Just like layers of paper, you want to have the dropdown at a higher level than the main content. Perhaps you've added an unnecessary `z-index: 1;` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your category & sub-category dropdown is supposed to have the highest series of z-index values as it will be an overlay on everything else on the website. I will recommend using the z-index as series of 10,100,1000 etc.; it will help you remember the placement and avoid errors. Change the z-index value to 100 for `.dropdown-contentCat`, this may solve the issue.

Comment: that means should i need to give z-index to category and sub category like this "z-index:100"

Comment: Yes that will separate them from any other z-index values you may have given, give it a shot and let me know if it works

Comment: Why do you have display: none; by default, are you changing the value via event triggers?

Comment: Try removing your display: none; property and temporarily disable the img tag in HTML to observe the subcategory?